# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in GameViewController

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I keep getting an error in my GameViewController..

This is my GameViewController:
How DO I get rid of this error:fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) , it is on the line " let sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile..."

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation
import Social

extension SKNode {
class func unarchiveFromFile(file : NSString) -> SKNode? {

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks")

    let sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile:path!, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
    let archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData!)

    archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
    let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as GameScene
    archiver.finishDecoding()
    return scene
}
}

class GameViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{







override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let skView = view as SKView

    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        println("gamescc")
    }

    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false
    scene = GameMenuScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    //scene.weakGameRef = self
    //scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.ResizeFill
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your file exist in your bundle.

Go to your project target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources and check is file exist there or not.If not add to bundle resource.

Also always check `optionals` with `if` condition or optional chaining before unwrapping it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a special characters " and ' inside the text. It is not regular ", but looks different and has caused by copy paste
I removed the unnecessary special characters and it resolved the issue. 
It is tricky to find the right character

In another file, i had this character ë which was ' in another windows file